# What is the difference between Ports and RPC for Erlang?

Tags: erlang

They are both the method for erlang to communicate with the external world from Erlang's point of view

So what is the difference and which performance is better ?

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, rpc (remote procedure calls) is a construct to call a function on a remote node (and get the result).

A port (in Erlang) is simply a communication point, not even (necessarily) to a remote node. You use ports, e.g., to communicate with another (non-Erlang) program.

Both constructs are for different purposes. No one is better, they are simply different. If you want, rpc is at a higher abstraction level than ports, but that doesn't make it better or worse.

Comment: @why Not really a higher abstraction layer. An rpc, though a NIF, behaves like a *function call* while a port behaves like a *process*. The rpc is sequential and blocking while the port is concurrent and non-blocking. Which tells you when you would use one over another.

Comment: You are in general right. However, some people see a synchronous function call as a higher abstraction since concurrency is a nasty detail to abstract from.

Comment: A slightly strange point of view considering concurrency is what Erlang is all about, and fault-tolerance of course.

Comment: :-) But abstraction is not about that something is applicable/practicable but about to omit something.

Comment: Yes, but you can't abstract away concurrency, only maybe abstract the wrapper around the concurrency. Concurrency, or lack off, will affect most other abstractions and their validity and application. Concurrent systems just don't behave like sequential systems, rpc is not an equivalent to function calls however much some would wish them to be. Grrrr :-)